# c# LINQ LIST Key, Results view, get values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm starting to use C # and LINQ, I think a list to filter a database that has repeated data by date and created a List, through ToList ().

```
 List<Registro> datosCalcA = new List<Registro>(); 
    MonitoreoEntities _context = new MonitoreoEntities();

   datosCalcA= _context.Registroes.Where(a => a.PuntoDeMedicionId == pPuntoDeMedicionId
                      && a.EntradaSalidaId == _operadorA
                      || a.EntradaSalidaId == _operadorB
                      && a.FechaHoraRegistro <= _fechaHoraFinal
                      && a.FechaHoraRegistro >= _fechaHoraInicial).OrderBy(i => i.FechaHoraRegistro).ToList();

var newList = datosCalcA.GroupBy(i => i.FechaHoraRegistro, x => new {Valor = x.Valor}).ToList();
```

I want to access the values that I have in the list.

If I use a breackpoint, I can see:

```
-       newList[0]  {System.Linq.Lookup<System.DateTime,<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal>>.Grouping} System.Linq.IGrouping<System.DateTime,<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal>> {System.Linq.Lookup<System.DateTime,<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal>>.Grouping}
+       [System.Linq.Lookup<System.DateTime,<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal>>.Grouping] {System.Linq.Lookup<System.DateTime,<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal>>.Grouping} System.Linq.Lookup<System.DateTime,<>f__AnonymousType0<decimal>>.Grouping
+       Key {05/12/2014 01:52:07 p.m.}  System.DateTime
-       Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable   
+       [0] { Valor = 29 }  <Anonymous Type>
+       [1] { Valor = 24 }  <Anonymous Type>
```

I have read the values 0 and 1.

- [0] { Valor = 29 }
- [1] { Valor = 24 }

I need to make the product between the two values and generate a new list with the result, the serious code as:

```
var newList = datosCalcA.GroupBy(i => i.FechaHoraRegistro, x => new {Valor = x.Valor}).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < newList.Count; i++) // Loop with for.
    {
     var datos = newList[i].First().Valor[0,i]*newList[i].First().Valor[1,i];

    }
```

With GroupBy, I group the data by date, and then I have to calculate a date for the products of the two data are in.

Before grouping I have:

**date1**
*Valor=29,
ID1*

**date1**
*Valor=24,
ID2*

**date2**
*Valor=24,
ID1*

**date2**
*Valor=23,
ID2*

After grouping, I lose IDxx, this is not any problem

**date1**
*Valor=29,
Valor=24*

**date2**
*Valor=25,
Valor=23*

With the data grouped by date

I need to calculate where value is the same variable, they are different fields within the record

```
+[0]    { Valor = 29 }  <Anonymous Type>
+[1]    { Valor = 24 }  <Anonymous Type>
```

**date1**
Valor * Valor  (29*24)

**date2**
Valor * Valor (24*23)

Not if the code is correct, is one of the ways I thought it could solve.

**I could solve.**

As is a list inside another list, I create a auxiliary list each major item, I take the values they have in each:

```
  var newList = datosCalcA.GroupBy(i => i.FechaHoraRegistro, x => new {x.Valor}).ToList();

             yy = 0;
             foreach (var _datosCalculado in newList)
             {
                 var valorW = newList[yy].ToList(); //auxiliary list to take values (Valor)
                 try
                 {
                     decimal resultado = valorW[0].Valor / valorW[1].Valor;// Take data in pos [0] and [1] in auxiliary list
                 }
                 catch (DivideByZeroException e)  //divide by zero error
                 {
                     decimal resultado = 0;
                 }
                 yy++;
             }
```

Comment: Its not clear What are you trying to do ? Can you provide sample data with expected output.You are creating the group using the `FechaHoraRegistro` as key and `Valor` as comparere  and if you need to go through each group you can use key to loop trough the groups and then do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your class looks like this:

```
 public class myClass
 {
     public int Valor1;
     public int Valor2;
 }
```

Now you make a list of myClass somehow, perhaps from getting data from db:

```
  List<myClass> myList = GetDataFromDatabase();  // Returns List<myClass>
```

Now you can make a new anonymous type or you can select into a different type like this

```
 var stuff = myList.Select(x => new { Product = x.Valor1 * x.Valor2 });
```

Comment: I do not use a class.
I am using EF and filtering.
Add the code to the top of the filtrate with EF

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
var ListProduct = from item in myList
select (item.Valor2 * item.Valor1);
```

Comment: Error 5 The name 'x' does not exist in the current context D:\Proyecto telemetria\SystemaControl\Graficos.aspx.cs 142 61 SystemaControl
Error 4 'System.Linq.IGrouping<System.DateTime,AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Valor2' and no extension method 'Valor2' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<System.DateTime,AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Proyecto telemetria\SystemaControl\Graficos.aspx.cs 142 52 SystemaControl

Comment: I made a mistake change x by item

Comment: We had tried before and the error:  Error' does not contain a definition for 'Valor1' and no extension method 'Valor1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<System.DateTime,AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Proyecto telemetria\SystemaControl\Graficos.aspx.cs 141 65 SystemaControl